# use data step generate next observation

Tags: sas

Case 1

Suppose the data are sorted by year then by month (always have 3 observations in data).

```
Year Month Index
2014 11    1.1
2014 12    1.5
2015 1     1.2
```

I need to copy the `Index` of last month to new observation

```
Year Month Index
2014 11    1.1
2014 12    1.5
2015 1     1.2
2015 2     1.2
```

Case 2

`Year` is removed from data. So we only have `Month` and `Index`.

```
Month Index
1     1.2
11    1.1
12    1.5
```

Data is always collected from consecutive 3 months. So `1` is the last month.

Still, ideal output is

```
Month Index
1     1.2
2     1.2
11    1.1
12    1.5
```

I solve it by creating another  dataset only contains `Month` (1,2...12). Then right join the original dataset twice. But I think there's more elegant way to deal with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1 can be a straight-forward data step. Add `end=eof` to the `set` statement to initialize a variable `eof` that returns value 1 when the data step is reading the last row of the data set. An output statement in the data step outputs a row during each iteration. If eof=1, a do block runs that increments the month by 1 and outputs another row.

```
data want;
  set have end=eof;
  output;
  if eof then do;
    month=mod(month+1,12);
    output;
  end;
run;
```

For case 2, I would switch to an sql solution. Self join the table to itself on month, incremented by 1 in the second table. Use the `coalesce` function to keep the values from the existing table if it exists. If not, use the values from the second table. Since a case crossing December-January will produce 5 months, limit the output to four rows using the `outobs=` option in `proc sql` to exclude the unwanted second January.

```
proc sql outobs=4;
create table want as
select
  coalesce(t1.month,mod(t2.month+1,12)) as month,
  coalesce(t1.index,t2.index) as index
from
  have t1
  full outer join have t2
  on t1.month = t2.month+1
order by
  coalesce(t1.month,t2.month+1)
;
quit;
```